# How to directly find WebElements by their attributes except "class" and "name" (for example "title")

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new at Java and Selenium so my apologies in advance if my question sounds a bit primary.

I use:

```
driverChrome.findElements(By.className("blabla"));
```

to find elements which have "blabla" as their className, for example:

```
<span class="blabla" title="the title">...</span>
```

Now, what if I want to find all elements by their other attributes? something like:

```
driverChrome.findElements(By.titleValue("the title"));
```

This is the code that I am currently using to do this task:

```
List<WebElement> spans = driverChrome.findElements(By.tagName("span"));

for (WebElement we : spans) {

    if (we.getAttribute("title") != null) {
            if (we.getAttribute("title").equals("the title")) {
                    ...
                    break;
            }
    }

}
```

but it is not fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many methods while archiving an element by **XPath**

## 1 Absolutely path

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="demo"/>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get the 'input' tag

```
xpath="/html/body/div/form/input"
```

## 2 Relative path

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="demo"/>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get the 'input' tag

```
xpath="//input"
```

## 3 Index

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="demo1"/>
          <input id="demo2"> 
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get the input 'demo2'

xpath="//input[1]"

## 4 Arbitrary single attribute

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="demo1"/>
          <input id="demo2" foo="bar"> 
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get input 'demo2'

```
xpath="//input[@id='demo2']" (equivalent to By.id)
```

Or

```
xpath="//input[@foo='bar']"
```

## 5 Arbitrary multiple attributes

```
<html>
    <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="1" type="submit" />
          <input id="2" foo="bar"/>
          <input id="3" type="submit" foo="bar"/> 
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get 3rd input

```
xpath="//input[@type='submit'][@foo='bar']"
```

Or

```
xpath="//input[@type='submit' and @foo='bar']"
```

If use xpath="//input[@type='submit' or @foo='bar']" here you'll get an array. You can get the List by driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)) (java). Otherwise you'll get the first element(If you just use driver.findElement). Because all of the 3 input elements meet your condition 'or' and it gives you the first one.

## 6 Contains attribute

```
<html>
    <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="1" type="submit" />
          <input id="2" foo="bar" daddy="dog"/>
          <input id="3" type="submit" foo="bar"/> 
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get the second input

```
xpath="//input[@daddy]"
```

Because only the second one has attribute 'daddy'

## 7 Inner searching

```
 <html>
    <body>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="input1" daddy="dog" />
          <input id="input2" daddy="pig"/>
       </form>
     </div>
     <div>
       <form>
          <input id="input3" daddy="dog" />
          <input id="input4" daddy="apple"/>
       </form>
     </div>
   </body>
 <html>
```

To get the second div

```
xpath="//div[.//input[@daddy='dog'] and .//input[@daddy='apple']]"
```

Overall those are all I can work out for now. Hope it helps.

Comment: That was awesome. WoooooW. Thanks indeed * 1000 :). just one little question, can I do all above with CSS too?

Comment: and also, in this case: <div class="blabla" title="blabla">Kevin</div> can I get to "Kevin" by xpath

Comment: Q1 - Basically CssSelector is different with the Xpath selector. If you are familiar with JQuery you will be easy to handle it. Share some primary examples here.

e.g  - use id  <input id="foo" name="bar" /> 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(#foo));  

e.g - use class <input id="foo" name="bar" class="jet" />
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(.jet));

e.g - use id and tag 
<button id="foo" name="bar"'>  (Here assume repeated id)
<div id="daddy">
<input id="foo" name="bar" />
</div>
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input#foo));
Or
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div#daddy input#foo));

Comment: If you want to know more about cssSelector you may ask Google...

Q2 - Surely you are easy to get text 'Kevin'. Example in java


String xPath = "//div[@class='blabla' and @title='blabla']"

String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText(); //get 'Kevin'

Also if you want to get such element by 'Kevin'

WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Kevin']"))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using xpath

```
driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@yourAttribute='value']"));
```

For example:

```
driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='the title']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using CSS locators.

By.cssSelector ("span[title='the title']")

CSS selector are rumoured to be faster.

We cover a number of locating techniques in Selenium WebDriver in Practice: http://selenium-webdriver-in-practice.github.io

Comment: CSS selectors are the way to go.. and they are faster. [CSS Selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

There a number of options you can go for.

1. by css selector
2. by xpath
3. by id
4. by tag
   For easy reading tutorials, please follow the links below:
   http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp
   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

All above is using element attributes, alternatively, you can use relationship among elements. Such as sibling, parents and children.

Please refer to this awesome link for more details. http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

There are also very well supported and established frameworks for you to use. For example, robot framework, it will vastly simplify your codes.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PLSMainContent_AssistTaskList_assistListView']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[7]/span"));

 System.out.println("get attribute is --> " + element.getAttribute("Title"));
```