# Is there any option to give multiple properties of any element in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium WebDriver script written in java language which I need to run in multiple sites. Basically script is written for 1 site but other sites also follow the the same architecture and element properties in those sites are also same. So my script work nearly fine in all those sites.

Problem is that, some element properties might be different in some site. So is there any option in Selenium WebDriver where I can pass multiple properties for an element.

Something like

```
String elemprop = "Prop1|Prop2|Prop3"  // Properties separated by Pipe
driver.findelement(By.id(elemprop)).click();
```

So when it execute, Selenium Webdriver should first check for Prop1 then Prop2 and then Prop3.

I have seen this feature in Rational functional tester. Wanted to know if Selenium Webdriver also gives this feature ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean is to check multiple properties and one of these properties are suitable for your current specific website's element, you may try to do like this(in java):

```
String xpath = "//*[@id='id1' or @id='id2' or @id='id3']";

driver.findElement(By.xPath(xpath));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted this as an answer but can we do something similar for other locators as well like id, name, css etc... ?

Comment: @Naseem Sure you can. Based on Xpath you can almost do everything you want. You can check mine and other's answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236054/how-to-directly-find-webelements-by-their-attributes-except-class-and-name/32242786#32242786

Comment: @Naseem BTW I suggest you do these configurations by a config file(e.g properties file) instead of hardcode. So that you are able to control it easily.  Setup key and value stuff then choose specific one per corresponding website.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check those links.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should consider using the Page Object Model in this scenario.  You could have a common ParentPage() that will define the common elements and methods among all of the pages that are similar, then different ChildPage1(), ChildPage2(), etc pages that will uniquely identify the controls but inherit from the parent.  Something like the following:

```
public class ParentPage {
    String xpath = null;
    public void commonMethod() {
        driver.findElement(By.xPath(xpath));
    }
}

public class ChildPage1 extends ParentPage {
    String xpath = "//*[@id='id1']";
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can generally reduce errors and complications that come from extended XPath definitions, and helps keep clear what each page is doing.